# How to overwrite dev server configuration using next.config.js

Tags: next.js, https, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to overwrite webpack dev server configurations using next.config.js file.
But its not getting applied and still the dev sever running http and default port 3000.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (
    config,
    { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }
  ) => {
    config.devServer = {
      port: 8080,
      https: true
    }
    return config
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

next.js version - 13.2.4

port can change running "npm run dev -p 8080", but I want to enable https flag as well.

Is it possible to run the dev server on https?

Comment: Did you try creating your own custom server file ?

Comment: @PrabhjeevNijjar No I didn't try that approach. Do I have to write routes as well if I write a custom server file?

Comment: No you don't have to make seprate routes, Your pages folder will handel the routing as is. Just follow any basic tutorial for custom server.